# How to I get rid of the zeros in the final column

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I'm working on an assignment of Applied Data Science.

**Question:**
Cut % Renewable into 5 bins. Group Top15 by the Continent, as well as these new % Renewable bins. How many countries are in each of these groups?
This function should return a Series with a MultiIndex of Continent, then the bins for % Renewable. Do not include groups with no countries.

This is my code:

```
def answer_twelve():

    Top15 = answer_one()
    ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
    Top15['Continent'] = Top15.index.to_series().map(ContinentDict)
    Top15['bins'] = pd.cut(Top15['% Renewable'],5)
    return pd.Series(Top15.groupby(by = ['Continent', 'bins']).size())#,apply(lambda x:s if x['Rank']==0 continue))
answer_twelve()
```

This is my output for the above code

```
Continent      bins            
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    0
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    0
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    0
Europe         (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    0
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    0
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (2.212, 15.753]     0
               (15.753, 29.227]    0
               (29.227, 42.701]    0
               (42.701, 56.174]    0
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
dtype: int64
```

Required output is

```
Continent      bins            
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
Europe         (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (56.174, 69.648]    1
Name: Countries, dtype: int64
```

I want to get rid of the zeros, i tried using

```
pd.Series(Top15.groupby(by = ['Continent', 'bins']).size().apply(lambda x:s if x['Rank']==0 continue))
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-317-14bc05bb2137>", line 20
    return pd.Series(Top15.groupby(by = ['Continent', 'bins']).size().apply(lambda x:s if x['Rank']==0 continue))
                                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm unable to figure out my mistake. Please help me!

Comment: `ds = answer_twelve()` and `ds[ds != 0]`

Comment: Thanks you very much it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas and just drop the rows when the column is zero

if column_name is your column:

```py
df = df[df.column_name != 0]
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this approach but couldn't print the output. Code ```top = Top15[Top15.Rank != 0]
    return pd.Series(Top15.groupby(by = [ContinentDict, bins]).size().apply(top))``` I guess I messed up. Please advise an approach

Comment: Please, create a minimal reproducible example so we can help with code

Comment: Here is the data that can be used to execute the function ```answer_twelve()```I couldn't make snippet of the source function, instead i can give the output file for answer_one(). The rest of the data is in answer_twelve() itself. Hope this might do the job. Sorry, if I couldn't provide enough resource. ```Here is the link for .csv file(output of answer_one()) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/11L2mDL73McEwNi35pULFHk6fYr0qlenE/view?usp=sharing```

Comment: @ShinigamiSinofWrath please follow community recommendations ->
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
lambda x:s if x['Rank']==0 continue
```

This doesn't make any sense, as `continue` is useful only within a loop.
Note that you need a value to print.  Instead, make it a blank:

```
lambda x:"" if x['Rank']==0 else s
```

Comment: Hey , Itried the approach but pretty sure made a mistake. Please help. Code ```pd.Series(Top15.groupby(by = [ContinentDict, bins]).size().apply(lambda x:"" if x['Rank']==0 else ""))``` in place of 's' i gave it blank.

Comment: Then edit the attempt into your question, per the posting guidelines.  "made a mistake" is not a problem specification.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'for' loop to iter through the values, and then use `replace()` to replace 0's with NaN,
now you can just drop them, with `dropna()`.
I tried using `drop()` or `droplevel()` instead of replacing them, but it didn't work.Here is my code:

```
for k,i in series_df.items():
    if i == 0:
        pd_series.replace(to_replace=i, value=np.nan, inplace=True)
        pd_series.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
print(pd_series)
```

You might need to change dtype of the result.The output was:

```
Continent      bins            
Asia           (2.212, 15.753]     4
               (15.753, 29.227]    1
Australia      (2.212, 15.753]     1
Europe         (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (15.753, 29.227]    3
               (29.227, 42.701]    2
North America  (2.212, 15.753]     1
               (56.174, 69.648]    1
South America  (56.174, 69.648]    1
dtype: int64
```